# C# Get cast exception with implemented explicit cast

Tags: c#, selenium, casting

I have outer function:

```
public int SetHeight(IWebElement column)
{
    ExtendedElement.Get(column).Click();
}
```

the `column` parameter it recieves in the call is of concrete type `ExtendedElement`already, but since it accepts any `IWebElement` I need that `Get` method.

Here's `ExtendedElement` important parts:

```
public class ExtendedElement : IWebElement
{
    private IWebElement _Element { get; set; }
    private ExtendedElement() {}

    public static ExtendedElement Get(IWebElement element)
    {
        return new ExtendedElement()
        {
            _Element = (RemoteWebElement)element
        };
    }

    public static explicit operator RemoteWebElement(ExtendedElement element)
    {
        return (RemoteWebElement)element._Element;
    }
    // other impmlementations
}
```

How to write the conversion I read from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators/)

And for some reason when the code is run I get the exception:
`System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Core.Helper.ExtendedElement' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement'.`

So, why's that? And if I'm over-complicating things and need to change the design - what should aim for?

Comment: Probably you meant type of `_Element` is `RemoteWebElement` and not `IWebElement`?

Comment: @Evk, doesn't work either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a customized web element which keeps its original methods, extend `RemoteWebElement`:

```
public class ExtendedElement : RemoteWebElement
{

    public static ExtendedElement Get(IWebElement element)
    {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = (RemoteWebDriver)element.WrappedDriver;
        string id = (string)typeof(RemoteWebElement)
                        .GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .GetValue(element, null);

        return new ExtendedElement(driver, id);
    }

    public ExtendedElement(RemoteWebDriver driver, string id)
        : base(driver, id)
    { }

}
```

Comment: Can't access `IWebElementReference` in  ((IWebElementReference)element), because it's internal, can't call `element.Id` instead, says `Cannot access protected member 'RemoteWebElement.Id' via a qualifier of type 'RemoteWebElement'; the qualifier must be of type 'ExtendedElement' (or derived from it)`

Comment: I missed that. One way around it would be to use reflexion to get the id. Another way is to call `string id = element.ToString(); id = id.Substring(14, id.Length - 15);`. You should open a ticket for lack of extensibility.

Comment: Tried this reflection and got null-reference exception: `base((RemoteWebDriver)element.WrappedDriver,
(string)element.GetType().GetProperty("Id",BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(element,null))`

Could you please update the answer with proper reflection usage?

Comment: Upd: managed to get it running with this: `(string)element.GetType().GetProperty("Id",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(element,null))`. Please update the answer, so that I could accept it. Thanks! I'd not figure this out myself for another month.

Comment: Have you tried directly with `element.ToString();` to get the id? Imo it would be cleaner.

Comment: This seems to have worked: `base((RemoteWebDriver)element.WrappedDriver,
element.ToString().Substring(14, element.ToString().Length - 15))`  Made it in one statement to keep the same constructor. Not sure about cleaner, what if framework developers change `ToString` output format? At least with reflection I get exactly what I ask for or null and would notice right away if it fails. Also I'm not sure that `Id`I'm getting is actually called to anywhere in my tests from the `ExtendedElement` object.